# How to connect atom with website and read the new content

Tags: xml, rss, atom-feed

I created an Atom rss file, how can I now link that with my website and read all the new content the file I created:

http://www.swqee.com/rss.xml in web http://swqee.com

Comment: Atom is not RSS. I checked your link, it looks like Atom.

Comment: @koan — In what way does it look like Atom? It has an `<rss>` root element containing a `<channel>` element. That's RSS.

Comment: You are right; it's RSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following line in the head of your webpage:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://www.swqee.com/rss.xml" title="swqee news">
```

This is for HTML, if you use XHTML don't forget to terminate the tag.

Comment: As your feed is RSS you should set `type="application/rss+xml"`.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a server side language. Find an Atom parser library and a template library for it. Use the Atom library to get data from the feed and put it into an HTML template.

It is, however, more usual to generate both Atom and HTML from a database.

Incidentally, what you have isn't Atom. It is an RSS document with a tiny bit of Atom embedded inside it. I recommend using plain Atom instead (since, unlike RSS, it has a single comprehensive specification).

Comment: its more complicated for me as beginner, but sure I will search and go through. Thanks a lot